# Failed to start greeter

Tags: 12.04, lightdm

After some pretty advanced configuration and kernel compilation, I've got EFI booting and Intel Graphics enabled on my MacBook Pro 8,3 and the ATI proprietary driver disabled in order to be able to save a lot of power and to keep the laptop a lot cooler in the process.

However, I can't seem to get `lightdm` to start. My `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` looks like this:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "0:2:0"
EndSection
```

I stripped everything out to allow things to more or less autoconfigure, but I want to be sure that X tries loading the Intel driver and not anything else.

In my `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`, I see the following:

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.2.3, UID=0 PID=14647
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loaded configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Adding default seat
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting seat
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting new display for greeter
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting local X display
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Launching X Server
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Launching process 14651: /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+0.30s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 14651
[+0.30s] DEBUG: Got signal from X server :0
[+0.30s] DEBUG: Connecting to XServer :0
[+0.31s] DEBUG: Starting greeter
[+0.31s] DEBUG: Started session 14656 with service 'lightdm', username 'lightdm'
[+0.35s] DEBUG: Session 14656 authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+0.35s] DEBUG: Greeter authorized
[+0.35s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log
[+0.35s] DEBUG: Session 14656 running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/share/xgreeters/pantheon-greeter
[+0.60s] DEBUG: Greeter closed communication channel
[+0.60s] DEBUG: Session 14656 exited with return value 0
[+0.60s] DEBUG: Greeter quit
[+0.60s] DEBUG: Failed to start greeter
[+0.60s] DEBUG: Stopping display
[+0.60s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 14651
[+0.97s] DEBUG: Process 14651 exited with return value 0
[+0.97s] DEBUG: X server stopped
[+0.97s] DEBUG: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.97s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+0.97s] DEBUG: Display server stopped
[+0.97s] DEBUG: Display stopped
[+0.97s] DEBUG: Stopping X local seat, failed to start a display
[+0.97s] DEBUG: Stopping seat
[+0.97s] DEBUG: Seat stopped
[+0.97s] DEBUG: Required seat has stopped
[+0.97s] DEBUG: Stopping display manager
[+0.97s] DEBUG: Display manager stopped
[+0.97s] DEBUG: Stopping daemon
[+0.98s] DEBUG: Exiting with return value 1
```

It seems to fail to start the greeter, but it doesn't get any more descriptive than this. I can't seem to find any other related logs. In the `Xorg.0.log`, I see this error:

```
[   477.378] (EE) GLX error: Can not get required symbols.
```

I don't know if this has anything to do with this issue, but yeah. Any ideas on why lightdm won't start? I was able to get X itself to start with `sudo startx`, but the greeter just won't launch :(

Answer (score 1):

`fglrx` still being installed was to blame here. Better [nuke it from orbit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCbfMkh940Q):

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx*
```